# Typescript Index Signature With `in`?

Tags: typescript

I am studying typescript, is there any difference between these two types?

```
type KeyInString =  {
  [key in string]: string
}

type KeyColonString =  {
  [key: string]: string
}

const test2: KeyColonString = {
  random: 'ASDAS',
  more: "asdadsa"
}

const test1: KeyInString = {
  random: 'ASDAS',
  more: "asdadsa"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one with `in` is called [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and the other one is [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

The difference is that you can't use a `index signature` with generic or literal type.

```
type Case1<T extends string> = {
  [key: T]: string; // An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)
};

type Case2 = {
  [key: 'a' | 'b']: string; // An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)
};
```

However, it is absolutely valid with `mapped types`:

````
type Case1<T extends string> = {
  [key in T]: string; // no error
};

type Case2 = {
  [key in 'a' | 'b']: string; // no error
};
```
````